# Hide div by default and show it on click with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show and hide a `div`, but I want it to be hidden by default and to be able to show and hide it on click. Here is the code that I have made :

```
<a class="button" onclick="$('#target').toggle();">
 <i class="fa fa-level-down"></i>
</a>

<div id="target"> 
 Hello world... 
</div>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just add water  `style="display:none";` to the `<div>`

Fiddles I say: http://jsfiddle.net/krY56/13/

jQuery:

```
function toggler(divId) {
    $("#" + divId).toggle();
}
```

Preferred to have a CSS Class `.hidden`

```
.hidden {
     display:none;
}
```

Comment: Ouda, strictly speaking, this is how you use jQuery to toggle. Not how you use bootstrap to do the same thing CowWarrior actually answered the question that you asked. Ouda's answer does "work" but it is not actually what you asked. Not sure what you can do about this.. but this is the reason why CowWarrior's answer is scoring so much better

Comment: @RolandiXor, I'm guessing that was because there is already a .hidden class in Bootstrap (at least there is now, as of v3.3.7) that sets `display:none !important` which is not overridden by the inline `display:block` which is set by `jQuery.toggle()`.

Answer (score 289):

Here I propose a way to do this exclusively using the [Bootstrap framework built-in functionality](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#collapse).

1. You need to make sure the target `div` has an ID.
2. Bootstrap has a `class` "collapse", this will hide your block by
   default. If you want your div to be collapsible AND be shown by
   default you need to add "in" class to the collapse. Otherwise the
   toggle behavior will not work properly.
3. Then, on your hyperlink (also works for buttons), add an href
   attribute that points to your target div.
4. Finally, add the attribute `data-toggle="collapse"` to instruct
   Bootstrap to add an appropriate toggle script to this tag.

Here is a code sample than can be copy-pasted directly on a page that already includes Bootstrap framework (**up to version 3.4.1**):

```
<a href="#Foo" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Toggle Foo</a>
<button href="#Bar" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Toggle Bar</button>
<div id="Foo" class="collapse">
    This div (Foo) is hidden by default
</div>
<div id="Bar" class="collapse in">
    This div (Bar) is shown by default and can toggle
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion, Bootstrap already has a very clean built-in to deal with that

Comment: clean and simple using bootstrap.

Comment: I know its an old question but to add to @CowWarriors answer you can replace the `href` attribute with a `data-target="#id-of-element-to-toggle"`.
This is particularly useful when creating accordions using bootstrap and you want to make an entire element clickable and not just a link. https://jsfiddle.net/clDjs/L8Lef3cx/1/

Comment: Can this be done programmatically, without using `<a>` or `<button>`?

Comment: In Bootstrap, I think you could do it this way: `$('#Foo').collapse('toggle');` programmatically according to [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-methods).

Comment: The target doesn't need an id. You can also work with classes and collapse/expand more than one element!

Comment: Is there any way in Bootstrap to collapse all `<div>` and show only the clicked `<div>`?

Comment: For anyone using Bootstrap 5, "data-toggle" has changed to "data-bs-toggle"

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/

Answer (score 17):

Try this one:

```
<button class="button" onclick="$('#target').toggle();">
    Show/Hide
</button>
<div id="target" style="display: none">
    Hide show.....
</div>
```

Comment: There is missing return false; in onclick method to prevent go to href and use class="collapse" instead style="display: none".

Answer (score 10):

I realize this question is a bit dated and since it shows up on Google search for similar issue I thought I will expand a little bit more on top of @CowWarrior's answer. I was looking for somewhat similar solution, and after scouring through countless SO question/answers and Bootstrap documentations the solution was pretty simple. Again, this would be using inbuilt Bootstrap `collapse` class to show/hide divs and Bootstrap's "Collapse Event".

What I realized is that it is easy to do it using a Bootstrap Accordion, but most of the time even though the functionality required is "somewhat" similar to an Accordion, it's different in a way that one would want to show hide `<div>` based on, lets say, menu buttons on a `navbar`. Below is a simple solution to this. The anchor tags (`<a>`) could be navbar items and based on a collapse event the corresponding div will replace the existing div. It looks slightly sloppy in CodeSnippet, but it is pretty close to achieving the functionality-

All that the JavaScript does is makes all the other `<div>` hide using

`$(".main-container.collapse").not($(this)).collapse('hide');`

when the loaded `<div>` is displayed by checking the Collapse event `shown.bs.collapse`. Here's the Bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#collapse-methods) on Collapse Event.

Note: `main-container` is just a custom class.

Here it goes-

```js
$(".main-container.collapse").on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {    
//when a collapsed div is shown hide all other collapsible divs that are visible
       $(".main-container.collapse").not($(this)).collapse('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#Foo" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Toggle Foo</a>
<a href="#Bar" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Toggle Bar</a>

<div id="Bar" class="main-container collapse in">
    This div (#Bar) is shown by default and can toggle
</div>
<div id="Foo" class="main-container collapse">
    This div (#Foo) is hidden by default
</div>
```

Comment: Not too dated for me. Just what I was looking for.