# Bootstrap Carousel: Change section under slider

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, slider, carousel

So I've got your typical Bootstrap Carousel, with three or four slides, and the problem that I'm having is that I want the section under the slider to change whenever a new slide comes up.  I tried maybe hiding that section and revealing the proper section using "collapse" like this: [Hide div by default and show it on click with bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873005/hide-div-by-default-and-show-it-on-click-with-bootstrap)

```
<a href="#Foo" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Toggle Foo</a>

<div id="Foo" class="collapse">
    This div (Foo) is hidden by default
</div>
```

...where the next slide would be "foo2", and then "foo3" etc... The problem there was that this didn't seem to work right for multiple slides.

Ideally I would want the bottom to fade out and then fade in with a div id corresponding to the id for the slide.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple code shows and hides the text under the Bootstrap Carousel, depending on the active slide.

You can setup collapsible `div`s by classes `for-slide-`. In my example slide 4 has no collapsible `div`. Slides 1 and 3 use the same `div`.

Please, check the result.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var forSlide = $('.for-slide-' + $(e.relatedTarget).index());
    if ( !forSlide.hasClass('in') ) {
      $('#collapseGroup>.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
      forSlide.collapse('show');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.well {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x650&text=Slide%200" alt="Slide 0">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption 0</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x650&text=Slide%201" alt="Slide 1">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption 1</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x650&text=Slide%202" alt="Slide 2">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption 2</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x650&text=Slide%203" alt="Slide 3">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption 3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x650&text=Slide%204" alt="Slide 4">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption 4</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="collapseGroup">
    <div class="collapse for-slide-0 in">
      <div class="well">
        <h3>Text for Slide 0</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse for-slide-1 for-slide-3">
      <div class="well">
        <h3>Text for Slides 1 and 3</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse for-slide-2">
      <div class="well">
        <h3>Text for Slide 2</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Looks great. But where do I place the first section of code? In the bootstrap.js? Or directly in the index.html?

Comment: @mysticcola First part of code shippet is a javascript. Wrap it in tags `<script>` and `<\script>`. And place it all at the end of `body` section of the `index.html`, just before the tag `</body>`. Look [standalone page](http://glebkema.ru/tasks/so-37265371/).