# How to change a section with text under a carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap carousel in my page, pretty standard. 
But I'd like to have the section under the slides change with each slide, but every option I try doesn't seem to work correctly. 
I'm also a major newbie, so that could be part of the problem.

I've tried collapsing the div inside the section, as told here [Bootstrap Carousel: Change section under slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265371/bootstrap-carousel-change-section-under-slider) but it doesn't quite work for what I want.
The problem with how my page is right now, is that the section is the same for all slides, as it's only one page...
Is it possible to change the section as I change the slides?

```html
<header>
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
                <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/2053922/pexels-photo-2053922.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940')">
                    <div class="slide__content">
                        <h2 class="slide__heading">First Slide</h2>
                        <p class="slide__text">This is a description for the first slide.</p>
                    </div>                    
                </div>

                <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
                <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/bF2vsubyHcQ/1920x1080')">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h2 class="display-4">Second Slide</h2>
                        <p class="lead">This is a description for the second slide.</p>
                    </div>                    
                </div>


                <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
                <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/szFUQoyvrxM/1920x1080')">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h2 class="display-4">Third Slide</h2>
                        <p class="lead">This is a description for the third slide.</p>
                    </div>                    
                </div>                       
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>

 <!-- Page Content -->
    <section class="py-5">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-4">Full Page Image Slider</h1>
                <p class="lead">The background images for the slider are set directly in the HTML using inline CSS. The images in this snippet are from <a href="https://unsplash.com">Unsplash</a>, taken by <a href="https://unsplash.com/@joannakosinska">Joanna Kosinska</a>!</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

The section is what I'd like to "move" with each slide, so the text could be unique to each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing carousel caption class. and use an image instead of making the background of the slide the image.  run the code snippet below

```css
.item img {width: 100%; height: auto}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->


  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2053922/pexels-photo-2053922.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Slide 1">
      <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tincidunt tortor vitae purus facilisis fringilla. Mauris egestas urna enim, vehicula placerat nibh mattis ut. Sed condimentum, metus ac ultricies varius, urna massa rhoncus leo, vel ultrices quam orci id est. Vestibulum nisl enim, dignissim vitae vehicula sed, egestas quis tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis faucibus volutpat arcu, eget molestie arcu malesuada quis. Duis sed nunc sit amet libero aliquam accumsan nec eu sapien.
      <p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://thehappypuppysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/marshmallows.jpg" alt="Slide 2">
      <div>
        <p>
        Vestibulum ultricies eu neque at suscipit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer at dui vel lectus sagittis tincidunt eu quis urna. Proin dapibus nisl id ipsum lacinia, quis euismod dui aliquam. Nulla nisi neque, aliquam id dolor eu, porttitor vehicula ante. Curabitur odio nisl, dignissim ac sem ac, luctus cursus eros. Quisque ornare cursus eros eget posuere. Proin in malesuada dui, et ultrices eros. Curabitur dictum leo arcu, quis pellentesque orci pretium a. In leo odio, accumsan eget elit sit amet, luctus efficitur nulla. Vivamus porta pharetra dictum. Nullam consectetur neque ante, sed vestibulum augue efficitur lobortis. Donec at neque porttitor, dapibus lectus nec, condimentum ligula.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://thehappypuppysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/puppy-search-2.jpg" alt="Slide 3">
      <div>
       <p>
       Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed fringilla volutpat ornare. Vivamus nunc justo, sollicitudin vitae hendrerit et, vestibulum nec justo. Praesent eu finibus purus. Maecenas vel eros malesuada mauris luctus consectetur. Nunc viverra porta diam, vel sagittis felis blandit ut. Sed elementum bibendum lectus, iaculis tempus ex suscipit et. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam eget magna sit amet metus blandit hendrerit in non elit. Quisque imperdiet sem nec laoreet rutrum. Pellentesque semper, odio eu iaculis euismod, orci orci maximus elit, eget suscipit nibh tellus a lacus. Praesent convallis est placerat nunc congue cursus eu eu risus. Etiam ante libero, tristique eu faucibus eget, posuere in erat. Maecenas elementum imperdiet tincidunt. Nulla ac ex quis quam ultricies volutpat sed quis sem.
       </p>
      </div>
    </div>        
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Things is, what I want to have is a section of text outside the slides that changes as they change too, because I'll be writing a lot so the caption isn't enough, it's too small for what I want.

Comment: ok lets go opposite then remove the carousel caption class like this http://jsfiddle.net/ewbydL0v/

Comment: I tried the code, and let's not pay much attention to this mess of a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4g8xoL1d/1/ , the carousel works fine on my page, but the error is the same as it shows on the fiddle, the dummy text appears at the top of the page

Comment: I updated my answer does that work for you? (removed background image of slide and used an actual img tag instead)

Comment: It does! Thank you, I'll have to tweek my CSS a bit now, but it finally works haha, cheers!